# How to make this layout? (Triple nested Div)

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I made a quick wireframe of what I'm trying to create down below.
I'm simply trying to just highlight 25% of the left side of the childDiv to be green, and 65% of the right side to be red.

I want to establish the correct spaces to have the left childInnerDiv to be green, and right childInnerDiv to be red. But it doesn't seem to work...

**What I'm trying to Create:**
[image]

**What I have:**

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8vhgq6k3/
[image]

**HTML Code**

```
        <div class="ProjectsParentDiv">
            <div class="childDiv">
                Foo
                <div class="childInnerDiv left">

                </div>
                <div class="childInnerDiv right">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="childDiv">
                Bar
            </div>
            <div class="childDiv">
                Baz
            </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS Code**

```
.ProjectsParentDiv {
    // position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: max-width;
    height: 40%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.childDiv {
    display: flex;
    background-color: lightblue;
    width: 75%;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 5px auto;
}

.childInnerDiv {
    //trying to make the childInnerDiv to be 95% height & width. of the ChildDiv
    height: 95%;
    width: 95%;
}

.childInnerDiv.left {
    flex: 25; //25% of the left side is a div for image.
    background: green;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.childInnerDiv.right {
    flex: 65; //65% of right side is a div for description
    background: red;
    border: 1px solid silver;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do below.

```css
.ProjectsParentDiv {
    // position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: max-width;
    height: 40%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.childDiv {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;;
    justify-content: space-around;
    background-color: lightblue;
    width: 75%;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 5px auto;
}

.childInnerDiv {
    display: flex;
    height: 95%;
}

.childInnerDiv.left {
    width: 25%; 
    background-color: green;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.childInnerDiv.right {
    width: 65%;
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid silver;
}
```

```html
<div class="ProjectsParentDiv">
    <div class="childDiv">
        <div class="childInnerDiv left">

        </div>
        <div class="childInnerDiv right">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="childDiv">
        Bar
    </div>
    <div class="childDiv">
        Baz
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice thank you :)! I also added Z-index to the childDiv and childInnerDivs too because the colors were being blocked for some reason.